# How to protect API routes even the application is running on shared server

Tags: laravel, hosting, shared-hosting

I am running my application on a Hostinger shared server. I am using ES6 JavaScript to send request to my laravel backend API. The API routes are visible on the browser network tab. This is my concern because if I am deploying on a AWS or Azure I can protect my API routes by a private network. But how can I protect it even on a shared server?

Comment: What is “protect”? What you want to see in network tab in browser?

Comment: protect from a potential attackers since the API routes are visible on the browser network tab. How can I protect my api even the application is running on a shared server.

Answer (score 0):

There is no risk that the route name be visible
You do not use the name in any part of the protection, and if you work in a normal website that is not SPA , the url appears normally in the browser location

Parts of the enduser must be visible, and you must make them so that they are compatible with SEO and can be archived by Google crawler

As for the control panel and the private parts, it relies on the token and the oauth to prevent the entry of anyone who does not have the powers to access